# Write logs to reach text box with serilog extensions

Tags: winforms, textbox, serilog

I saw this extension to Serilog that proides writing logs to text box on WinForms..
https://github.com/umairsyed613/Serilog.Sinks.WinForms
What I did not understand, is how I decide on the textbox that I want to write to.
Or there is another step to do that I didn't noticed?

Comment: There's a [winform example in the github source](https://github.com/umairsyed613/Serilog.Sinks.WinForms/blob/master/src/Sample/CustomSimpleTextLog/Form1.cs) that shows how to wire up a textbox and a rich textbox.

Comment: If you'd like to display the logs with colors you might want to take a look at [Serilog.Sinks.RichTextBox](https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-sinks-richtextbox). There's an [example on how to use it with Windows Forms](https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-sinks-richtextbox/tree/master/sample/WinFormsHostNet50Sample) in the repo.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Here are the steps to use it:

1. download the library "`Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.WinForms`" or use NuGet. I used VS2019 package manager console to install mine.
2. This part i missed and it took me a while to get. You need to add "SeriLog Control" from the toolbox menu. So search toolbox menu and add the gidLog1 control.
3. Configure your logger (i did mine in the Form load event.)

   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .WriteToGridView()
   .CreateLogger();
4. Perform/trigger a log action, you can add to you form load event too eg. below.

   Log.Information("Application Started");